# Is it not possible to filter SVG <line> elements?

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I have some  elements inside an SVG on this page: [digitalbrent.com/cv](http://www.digitalbrent.com/cv/). The lines I'm talking about are the ones next to the image of the pixel guy. I'd like to add an effect to these lines to get them to appear to have a kind of glow or haze similar to the green lettering next to the lines. I figured the best way to do that was probably to add a subtle gaussian blur SVG filter to the lines. I tried to apply [the filter from this guy's similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35174119/svg-filter-is-not-working-properly-for-straight-line) using the following methods:

```
<line x1="225" y1="20" x2="225" y2="30" stroke-width="2" stroke="#00fc49" filter="url(#glowing);"></line>

<line x1="225" y1="20" x2="225" y2="30" stroke-width="2" stroke="url(#glowing);"></line>
```

^ None of those methods worked for implementing the filter. Here is the whole code for the lines and SVG element (Sorry about the indentation. It didn't copy correctly from my ide.):

```
<svg id="line-underlay" width="450" height="300" viewBox="0 0 450 300">
<defs xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<filter id="glowing" height="100%" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3" result="coloredBlur"/>
<feOffset dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetblur" />
<feMerge>
<feMergeNode in="coloredBlur"/>
<feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
</feMerge>
</filter>
</defs>

<line x1="225" y1="20" x2="225" y2="30" stroke-width="2" stroke="#00fc49" filter="url(#glowing);"></line>
<line x1="150" y1="30" x2="300" y2="30" stroke-width="2" stroke="#00fc49"></line>
<line x1="150" y1="30" x2="150" y2="40" stroke-width="2" stroke="#00fc49"></line>
<line x1="300" y1="30" x2="300" y2="40" stroke-width="2" stroke="#00fc49"></line>
<line x1="320" y1="75" x2="350" y2="75" stroke-width="2" stroke="#00fc49"></line>
<line x1="320" y1="75" x2="320" y2="112" stroke-width="2" stroke="#00fc49"></line>
<line x1="284" y1="112" x2="320" y2="112" stroke-width="2" stroke="#00fc49"></line>
<line x1="97" y1="106" x2="160" y2="106" stroke-width="2" stroke="#00fc49"></line>
<line x1="295" y1="136" x2="330" y2="136" stroke-width="2" stroke="#00fc49"></line>
<line x1="300" y1="185" x2="320" y2="185" stroke-width="2" stroke="#00fc49"></line>
<line x1="320" y1="185" x2="320" y2="202" stroke-width="2" stroke="#00fc49"></line>
<line x1="320" y1="202" x2="330" y2="202" stroke-width="2" stroke="#00fc49"></line>
<line x1="65" y1="206" x2="65" y2="220" stroke-width="2" stroke="#00fc49"></line>
<line x1="65" y1="220" x2="140" y2="220" stroke-width="2" stroke="#00fc49"></line>
<line x1="300" y1="242" x2="320" y2="242" stroke-width="2" stroke="#00fc49"></line>
<line x1="320" y1="242" x2="320" y2="260" stroke-width="2" stroke="#00fc49"></line>

</svg>
```

I've searched a few different sources, including [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638169/svg-line-with-gradient-stroke-wont-display-straight) which was similar but after trying the solution there, it still didn't seem to work. I also tried applying a box-shadow to the line elements using css but that didn't work either. I've found nothing at all in my search that indicates that you can apply a filter to `<line>` and now that I think about it I've never seen anyone actually do it in their code. I'm starting to wonder if this is even possible? If it is, what am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to do this?

If you have any alternative way of achieving the blur effect that I'm looking for, please let me know. I'd be very grateful for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've two problems

- the ; at the end of the url in the filter attribute is invalid
- the filter is in a different place to the shape so you don't see it. I've resized and moved the filter below

```html
<svg width="450" height="300" viewBox="200 15 50 20">
<defs>
<filter id="glowing" x="210" y="10" height="30" width="25" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3" result="coloredBlur"/>
<feOffset dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetblur" />
<feMerge>
<feMergeNode in="coloredBlur"/>
<feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
</feMerge>
</filter>
</defs>

<line x1="225" y1="20" x2="225" y2="30" stroke-width="2" stroke="#00fc49" filter="url(#glowing)"></line>


</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Robert. I tried your answer and it did give me gaussian blur effect on the line that you drew (I couldn't tell at first because my background is black and the blur blended right in. I'm not sure how to turn it green but that's a subject for some research outside of this question). This method works and I have a lot more to learn about SVGs, but I'd like to know if I understand this correctly: So I need to create a new filter for each line and place it right where the line is correct? I can't just apply one filter to each line like you would a CSS class right?

Comment: It's hard with horizontal and vertical lines as they have no height or width (except by dint of their stroke). Filters are mos easily reusable on things that do have height and width as you can use objectBoundingBox units there. Otherwise you'll need to draw all the lines at the same place and translate them to where you want them to be using a transform on a parent element so their local co-ordinates are identical and the same filter can be applied to them.